# To find out the level of level-by-level tree traversal

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I am wondering how to find out the level where each node is.
But I can't figure it out.

Here is the part of the section of the code, but I have to modify it.

```
if(root == NULL)
return;
q.enqueue(root);
while(!queue.empty()){
 queue.dequeue(cur);
 if( cur != NULL){
   cout<<cur->data<<" ";
   if(cur->left != NULL)
   queue.enqueue(cur->left);
   if(cur->right != NULL)
   queue.enqueue(cur->right);
  }
}
```

How to modify the code, so that I can know the level of each node ?
Hope you guys can give me some algorithms about this question.

Comment: Seems like C++ so I tagged it as such.

Comment: What have you tried so far? -- [WhatHaveYouTried.com](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing level order traversal which is in the correct direction. If you need to print which level you are at:

```
if(root == NULL)  
   return;  
int level = 1;  
q.enqueue(root);  
q.enqueue(NULL);    
while(!queue.empty()){  
 queue.dequeue(cur);  
 if(cur == NULL){  
    //going to next level  
    level++;      
    if(queue.empty()){  
       break;  
    }  
    queue.enqueue(NULL);  
 }    
 else {  
   cout << "LEVEL is: " << level;  
   cout<<cur->data<<" ";
   if(cur->left != NULL){
      queue.enqueue(cur->left);  
   }  
   if(cur->right != NULL){  
      queue.enqueue(cur->right);  
   }  
 }    
}
```

Comment: You use `NULL` to indicate the end of each level.